# how to remove logout and loggedout paged from asp.net identityserver3

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I just want a simple single sign-on for my application and identityserver3 seen to be a good solution. three things i didn't like about it though the consent page, the logout  and logged out pages. i manage to disable the consent page by setting these lines to the Clients.cs file

```
RequireConsent = false,
AllowRememberConsent = false,
```

i also added custom view following the docs on Custom View Service.

so now How do I disable the logout and loggedout pages so that it automatically send the user to the home page when they clicks the sign out button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/authenticationOptions.html) will help you. You are interested in specifying a custom set of `AuthenticationOptions`. Within that, there are three properties of interest:

1. `EnableSignOutPrompt`

   > Indicates whether IdentityServer will show a confirmation page for sign-out. When a client initiates a sign-out, by default IdentityServer will ask the user for confirmation. This is a mitigation technique against “logout spam”. Defaults to true.
2. `EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect`

   > Gets or sets a value indicating whether IdentityServer automatically redirects back to a validated post_logout_redirect_uri passed to the signout endpoint. Defaults to false.
3. `PostSignOutAutoRedirectDelay`

   > Gets or sets the delay (in seconds) before redirecting to a post_logout_redirect_uri. Defaults to 0.

Using these three settings you should be able to tweak IdentityServer3 to your liking.

For example, your `Startup.cs` may look like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    EnableSignOutPrompt = false,
                    EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
                    PostSignOutAutoRedirectDelay = 0
                },
                EnableWelcomePage = false,
                Factory = Factory.Get(),
                SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
                SiteName = "Identity Server Example"
            });
        });
    }
}
```